# How to convert rows into column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table,

[image: table 1]

and need to convert it as

[image: table 2]

I have tried pivot but can't figure out please help me out .

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of rows you want to merge? Otherwise, I would recommend to parse the data to an array

Comment: Yes I need to marge Id Code and Employeename  @shakedzy

Comment: You didn't answer the question.. Do you have a **fixed** number of rows for every ID?

Comment: No It's not fixed @shakedzy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Pivot does not work with more than one column *out-of-the-box* There are several approaches to solve this:

Use this table variable for all tests and please state your sample data always copy'n'pasteable. Best was a MCVE (Minimal Complete Verifyable Example) where you set up some code like mine here.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, Code INT,EmployeeName VARCHAR(100),ExamName VARCHAR(100),Board VARCHAR(100),Result VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (11537,12984,'TheName','SSC','b04','1st')
,(11537,12984,'TheName','HSC','b04','2nd')
,(11537,12984,'TheName','BA(H)','u33','2nd');
```

This is code to first concatenate your data to one single column. This allows `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT tbl.ID
        ,tbl.Code
        ,tbl.EmployeeName
        ,'Exam_' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.ID ORDER BY tbl.Code) AS VARCHAR(100)) AS ColName
        ,ExamName + ' (' + Board + '): ' + Result AS Concatenated
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
) AS t
PIVOT
(
    MIN(Concatenated) FOR ColName IN(Exam_1,Exam_2,Exam_3 /*add as many as you need*/)
) AS p
```

The result:

```
11537   12984   TheName SSC (b04): 1st  HSC (b04): 2nd  BA(H) (u33): 2nd
```

The next code does quite the same, but creates XML instead of plain text, which allows to separate your data afterwards:

```
SELECT p.ID
      ,p.Code
      ,p.EmployeeName
      ,E1
      ,E1.value('(/exam/@ExamName)[1]','varchar(100)') AS ExamName1
      ,E1.value('(/exam/@Board)[1]','varchar(100)') AS Board1
      ,E1.value('(/exam/@Result)[1]','varchar(100)') AS Result1
      ,E2
      ,E2.value('(/exam/@ExamName)[1]','varchar(100)') AS ExamName2
      ,E2.value('(/exam/@Board)[1]','varchar(100)') AS Board2
      ,E2.value('(/exam/@Result)[1]','varchar(100)') AS Result2
      ,E3
      ,E3.value('(/exam/@ExamName)[1]','varchar(100)') AS ExamName3
      ,E3.value('(/exam/@Board)[1]','varchar(100)') AS Board3
      ,E3.value('(/exam/@Result)[1]','varchar(100)') AS Result3
FROM
(
    SELECT tbl.ID
        ,tbl.Code
        ,tbl.EmployeeName
        ,'Exam_' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.ID ORDER BY tbl.Code) AS VARCHAR(100)) AS ColName
        ,(SELECT ExamName AS [@ExamName],Board AS [@Board],Result AS [@Result] FOR XML PATH('exam')) AS AsXML
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
) AS t
PIVOT
(
    MIN(AsXML) FOR ColName IN(Exam_1,Exam_2,Exam_3 /*add as many as you need*/)
) AS p
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT CAST(p.Exam_1 AS XML) AS E1
          ,CAST(p.Exam_2 AS XML) AS E2
          ,CAST(p.Exam_3 AS XML) AS E3
) AS CastedToXml
```

The result:

```
11537   12984   TheName <exam ExamName="SSC" Board="b04" Result="1st" />    SSC b04 1st <exam ExamName="HSC" Board="b04" Result="2nd" />    HSC b04 2nd <exam ExamName="BA(H)" Board="u33" Result="2nd" />  BA(H)   u33 2nd
```

This is *old-fashioned-pivot* which is quite often better then normal pivot:

```
;WITH Numberd AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.ID ORDER BY tbl.Code) AS Number
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT ID,Code,EmployeeName
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Number=1 THEN ExamName END) AS ExamName1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Number=1 THEN Board END) AS Board1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Number=1 THEN Result END) AS Result1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Number=2 THEN ExamName END) AS ExamName2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Number=2 THEN Board END) AS Board2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Number=2 THEN Result END) AS Result2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Number=3 THEN ExamName END) AS ExamName3
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Number=3 THEN Board END) AS Board3
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Number=3 THEN Result END) AS Result3
FROM Numberd
GROUP BY ID,Code,EmployeeName
```

The last option was dynamic SQL...

Answer (score 0):

Thnak you all , But My purpose is solved with this

```
SELECT 
      he.Id,he.Code,he.Name EmployeeName,en.Name [ExamName],bu.Name        
      [Board],[Result] = CASE WHEN 
             ac.GPA IS NULL THEN ac.Result ELSE CAST(ac.GPA AS VARCHAR) END,
      ac.PassingYear 
INTO #Temp 
FROM H_Employee AS he 
INNER JOIN 
      H_AcademicQualification AS ac ON ac.H_EmployeeId = he.Id 
INNER JOIN 
      ExamName AS en ON en.Id = ac.ExamNameId 
INNER JOIN 
      GroupSubject AS gs ON gs.Id = ac.GroupSubjectId 
INNER JOIN 
      BoardUniversity AS bu ON bu.Id = ac.BoardUniversityId
```

Then

```
SELECT
     a.id, a.Code, a.EmployeeName, a.ExamName, a.Board, a.Result, a.Passingyear, 
     b.ExamName, b.Board, b.Result, b.Passingyear, 
     c.ExamName, c.Board, c.Result, c.Passingyear, 
     d.ExamName, d.Board, d.Result, d.Passingyear 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
          Id, Code, EmployeeName ,ExamName = CASE WHEN 
               ExamName LIKE 'S.S.%' THEN 'S.S.C' END,
          Board=Board ,[Result]=CASE WHEN 
               Result IS NULL THEN Result ELSE CAST(Result AS VARCHAR) END,
          Passingyear 
     FROM #temp 
     WHERE ExamName LIKE 'S.S.%') AS a 
LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT Id, Code, EmployeeName ,ExamName = CASE WHEN 
            ExamName LIKE 'H.S.%' THEN 'H.S.C' END,
         Board=Board,[Result] = CASE WHEN 
            Result IS NULL THEN Result ELSE CAST(Result AS VARCHAR) END,
         Passingyear  
         FROM #temp 
         WHERE ExamName LIKE 'H.S.%') AS b 
     ON a.Id=b.Id 
LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT Id, Code, EmployeeName ,ExamName = CASE WHEN 
             ExamName LIKE 'B.%' THEN 'Graduate' END, 
         Board=Board, [Result] = CASE WHEN 
             Result IS NULL THEN Result ELSE CAST(Result AS VARCHAR) END,
         Passingyear 
         FROM #temp 
         WHERE ExamName LIKE 'B.%') AS c 
     ON a.Id=c.Id 
LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT Id, Code, EmployeeName, ExamName = CASE WHEN
             ExamName LIKE 'M.%' THEN 'Post-Graduate' END, 
         Board=Board,[Result] = CASE WHEN 
             Result IS NULL THEN Result ELSE CAST(Result AS VARCHAR) END,
         Passingyear 
         FROM #temp 
         WHERE ExamName LIKE 'M.%') AS d 
     ON a.Id=d.Id
```

Above query serve me purposes but will try @Shnugo Sample , Any way thank you all .

Comment: I'm glad, that you've found an answer yourself. If you check my code and it works for you, it would be kind to accept it as answer, first to close this issue, secondly to help future visitors to find an answer for the actual question and third: This pays points to your and to my account :-)